# How to understand Spring MVC Workflow?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I currently would like to expand my knowledge on Spring MVC so I am investigating the sample web apps that the spring distribution has.  I am basically checking the Petclinic application.

In the GET method, the Pet object was added into the model attributes so the JSP can access the javabean properties.  I think I understand this one.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/addPet.do")
@SessionAttributes("pet")
public class AddPetForm {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String setupForm(@RequestParam("ownerId") int ownerId, Model model) {
        Owner owner = this.clinic.loadOwner(ownerId);
        Pet pet = new Pet();
        owner.addPet(pet);
        model.addAttribute("pet", pet);
        return "petForm";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processSubmit(@ModelAttribute("pet") Pet pet, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {
        new PetValidator().validate(pet, result);
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "petForm";
        }
        else {
            this.clinic.storePet(pet);
            status.setComplete();
            return "redirect:owner.do?ownerId=" + pet.getOwner().getId();
        }
    }
}
```

But the thing that I cannot understand is during the POST operation.  I look up at my firebug, and I notice that my post data are only the data that was entered by the user which to me is fine.

[image]

But when I inspect the data on my controller.  The owner info is still complete.  I look up at the generated HTML from the JSP but I cannot see some hidden information about the Owner object.  I am quite not sure where does Spring gather the info on the owner object.

Does this mean that Spring is caching the model objects per each thread request?

[image]

This is for Spring MVC 2.5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key to this behavior is `@SessionAttributes("pet")` which means that the `pet` attribute of the model will be persisted in the session. In `setupForm` you perform the following operations:

```
    Pet pet = new Pet();
    owner.addPet(pet);
    model.addAttribute("pet", pet);
```

Which means: create an `Pet` object, add it to the owner specified in the request (`@RequestParam("ownerId") int ownerId`), this is probably where the pet owner attribute gets set.

In the `processSubmit` method, you declare `@ModelAttribute("pet") Pet pet` in the method signature which means that you want the `Pet` object you previously store in the session. Spring retrieves this object and then merge it with whatever had been set in the JSP. Hence a filled owner id.

More information in the [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-sessionattrib)

Comment: ... Stored in "conversational state" (not in HttpSession directly) that can be cleared with SessionStatus.setComplete() without affecting other parts of HttpSession state.